# Design 12-bit forward error correction code

Tags: coding-theory

I'm looking for an forward error correction mechanism that satisfies the following constraints:

1. Encodes **4 or more** input data bits into a **12**-bit word (adding **8 or less** redundancy bits)
2. Corrects **2** or more errors

Any ideas?

---

What I've seen so far:

- It can't be done by using *12-bit Hamming codes* since it can only correct up to 1 error (violating constraint number *2*)
- I'm not sure if it can be achieved by [general BCH codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCH_code#General_BCH_codes) (unfortunately it's beyond my math comprehension). I know that QR Codes use a (18,6) BCH to encode version bits (ISO 18004, page 78), which is (from my understanding) not a primitive narrow-sense one.
- There is something called [Binary Golay Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code) that can correct **3** bits from a **12**-bit input encoded into a **23**-bit word. Is there any magic that can 'make it work' for **12** bits? (I know this is quite vague, but who knows...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BCH-code with length $n=2^4-1=15$ and designed minimum distance $d=5$ has dimension $k=15-2\cdot4=7$. If you shorten that in three positions you get a binary linear $[12,4,5]$-code which is exactly what you need.

---

In a comment you ask whether this is code is optimal in the sense that can we have
a code with minimum distance $\ge6$. I don't know the answer to that question right away, if we limit ourselves to binary linear codes. However, a non-linear code of length $12$, $2^4=16$ words and minimum distance $d=6$ can be constructed by shortening the famous
$\Bbb{Z}_4$-linear Nordstrom-Robinson code. See [my answer to an earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118972/11619) for a description of the Nordstrom-Robinson code. With that code you are guaranteed to be able to correct all errors of at most two bits, and detect the occasions (but not uniquely decode) when exactly three bit errors have occured.

Comment: Do ask, if you need more details such as a generator polynomial or...

Comment: That sounds good. I apologize for my lack of knowledge about BCH codes, but what do you mean by short in three positions? I know that I can generate a (15, 7) BCH code using g(x) = x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + 1 (the codewords are listed here: http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/polygen2.pl?d=7&p=111010001&c=1). What would be the codewords from this (12, 4) code?

Comment: Ok, I get it now. The (12,4) codewords would be a subset of the (15,7) codewords, specifically from  0 to 15 so the 3 most significant bits can be ignored. Just a quick question: does the fact that I would be ignoring 3 bits make this code inefficient form a capacity perspective? Is there another technique (maybe not a BCH code) that would optimize the distance between the 12 bit codewords so that the minimum distance would be greater than 5? Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Shortening a code at a bit position means that you only include those words that have zeros in that position. When you do that you cut the dimension by one, and reduce the length by one (because it would be pointless to transmit a bit, if it is known to be zero for all legal codewords). So what I suggested is to take a $(15,7)$ code, only include the words that end with three zeros, and then throw away those three positions. It sounds like you got it right. The words are polynomials of the form $a(x)g(x)$ with $a(x)$ of degree $\le3$ (so that $a(x)g(x)$ will be of degree $\le11$).

Comment: Well, this makes everything more clear. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the generator matrix for a [12,4,6] code found with gap software
(+guava package); this should be the best linear code with these parameters.

100001111010

010010110110

001011101111

000100011111

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thanks for the effort. I'll upvote your answer as soon as I get enough reputation.

Comment: Good job. Observe that $6$ is definitely the largest possible minimum distance. By the Griesmer bound a $4$-dimensional code with minimum distance $7$ has length at least $7+4+2+1=14$.

Comment: i forgot about that bound; so the [12,4,6] code hits it exactly. Here's the G matrix for a [14,4,7] code that also hits the bound exactly with dmin=7:(10000111011010,01001011101001,00101110001111,00010001111111)