# Showing that the Nordstrom-Robinson code is not linear

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I have to show that the Nordstrom-Robinson code $N$ is non-linear.
I wanted to show this by finding a counter example to linearity:

Suppose for contradiction that $N$ is a linear $(16, 256, 6)$-code. 
Then by definition of linear code, $N \subseteq \Bbb{Z} {_2}^{16}$ is also a subspace of $\Bbb{Z} {_2}^{16}$.

By a theorem, since $N$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{Z} {_2}^{16}$, then it is closed under addition, such that if $x,y \in N$ then $x+y \in N$, and under scalar multiplication, such that if $a \in \Bbb{Z}_{3}$ and $x \in N$ then $ax \in N$.

I wanted to find a counter example for this, however I am having a hard time doing so without the generator matrix of $N$.

I know that $N$ is the code whose codewords are obtained by deleting the first 8 coordinate positions from the 256 words whose first 8 coordinates are one of $00000000, 10000001, 01000001, 00100001, 00010001, 00001001, 00000101, 00000011$ generated by the generator matrix $G'$, where $G'$ is obtained from the generator matrix of the Golay code $g_{24}$.

I think there is something simple that I am missing, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: I know there is no linear $(16, 256, 6)$ in general, but I am asked to prove that in another problem.

Comment: How is the Nordstrom-Robinson code described to you? I'm partial to its description as a $\Bbb{Z}_4$-linear code, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118972/11619). Then you can just look for two words such that their binary sum is not a codeword. I would guess that this is the way to go no matter how the NR-code is given to you.

Comment: Never mind, you do give a descrition. I stopped reading too soon! Nevertheless, you should specify **which** generator matrix of the Golay code is used. There are several ways of describing it. All equivalent, but in different bit orders. Knowing the exact bit order is essential here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two codewords $\mathbf{r_1}$ and $\mathbf{r_2}$ represented as the first two rows of $G'$. We may write
    $$\mathbf{r_1} = 10000001\mathbf{c} \qquad \text{and} \qquad 
 \mathbf{r_2} = 01000001\mathbf{d}$$
    where it's clear that $\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{d} \in \mathcal{N}$. Then the sum $\mathbf{r_1} + \mathbf{r_2} = 11000000(\mathbf{c} + \mathbf{d})$ has such a prefix that implies $(\mathbf{c} + \mathbf{d}) \not\in \mathcal{N}$. Thus $\mathcal{N}$ is not linear.