# Weight enumerator classifiers

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. What conditions guarantee that this is the weight enumerator of a binary linear code of size $n$ and dimension $k$?

I’m almost certain that the answer to this question is unknown...so instead i’ll settle for anything that is conjectural.

There’s a list of necessary conditions:

1. $f$ must be homogeneous of degree $n$ with non-negative coefficients.
2. The $x^n$ coefficient has to be $1$ since the zero vector is the unique weight $0$ vector.
3. The $y^n$ coefficient has to be $0$ or $1$ since the all $1$’s vector either belongs to the code or doesn’t.
4. The sum of the coefficients has to be $2^k$ since every vector has a unique weight and so is counted exactly once by some coefficient.
5. The MacWilliams transform ($g(x,y) = \frac{1}{2^k}f(x+y,x-y)$) has to have all of the above properties but with coefficient sum $2^{n-k}$ since if $f$ corresponds to a code then $g$ would correspond to the dual code.

Are there any more necessary conditions missing?

Comment: This has to be unknown. There are many subtleties. The first that springs to mind is the weight enumerator of the (non-linear!) binary Nordstrom-Robinson code:
$$f(x,y)=x^{16}+112x^{10}y^6+30x^8y^8+112x^6y^{10}+y^{16}.$$ The weight enumerator is its own self-dual, but it is known that no linear code with this enumerator exists. The NR code can be constructed as the Gray image of a $\Bbb{Z}_4$-linear code (so its distance distribution is codeword independent). This was a hot theme in the 90s.

Comment: There are other similar cases revolving around the weight enumerators of self-dual codes whose existence is yet unknown. I don't know of any conjectures about necessary and sufficient conditions. Those would make many difficult non/existence questions "computational" :-)

Comment: If you want to play with the Nordstrom-Robinson code, [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118972/11619) has a description of it as a submodule of $\Bbb{Z}_4^8$. The binary version is the Gray image.

Comment: Should have written that $f(x,y)$ is self-dual, i.e. equal to its own MacWilliams transform.

Comment: I’m looking for weight enumerators of all linear codes, not just self dual ones, so the MacWilliam’s transform shouldn’t preserve f in general.

Comment: Thanks for the Nordstrom-Robinson example, I like that it distinguishes the question between all codes and just linear ones.

Comment: Understood. A weight enumerator being preserved is a very special case. I brought it up mostly because it is somewhat famously an open problem whether self-dual codes having those enumerators exist. So some kind of examples supporting the claim that this is a very difficult question also in general.

Comment: There are other Gray images of $\Bbb{Z}_4$-linear codes with better minimum distance than any linear code. Most of them are not self-dual. Search with the buzzword "$\Bbb{Z}_4$-linear codes" for a lot of material (mostly from the 90s, but there are sporadic more recent articles also).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to make it clear that I think weight enumerators of Gray images of $\Bbb{Z}_4$-codes satisfy your constraints, but don't necessarily come from a binary linear code. That's why they could be interesting in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP has stated that he is not interested in only the case of (binary) self-dual codes but in linear codes in general, let us restrict ourselves to self-dual codes. Then the code must have even block length.  Furthermore, a result of Gleason (A. M. Gleason, Weight Polynomials of Self-Dual Codes and the MacWilliams Identities, *1970 Act. Congr. Int. Math.,* vol. 3, pp. 211-215, Paris:Gauthier-Villars, 1971) says that the weight enumerator of such a code can be expressed as a polynomial in
$x^2+y^2$ and $x^2y^2(x^2-y^2)^2 = x^6y^2-2x^4y^4+x^2y^6$. The shortest self-dual code is the $[2,1]$ repetition code with weight enumerator
$$x^2+y^2 = 1\cdot\big(x^2+y^2\big) + 0\cdot\big(x^6y^2-2x^4y^4+x^2y^6\big).$$
The well-known $[8,4]$ Hamming code has weight enumerator
$$x^8+14x^4y^4+y^8 = 1\cdot\big(x^2+y^2\big)^4 - 4\cdot \big(x^6y^2-2x^4y^4+x^2y^6\big)$$
However, not all polynomials in $x^2+y^2$ and $x^2y^2(x^2-y^2)^2$ that simplify to polynomials in $x$ and $y$ with all coefficients positive are necessarily weight enumerators of self-dual codes. For example,
$$x^8+3x^6y^2+8x^4y^4+3x^2y^6 + y^8 = 1\cdot\big(x^2+y^2\big)^4 - 1\cdot \big(x^6y^2-2x^4y^4+x^2y^6\big)$$
*is* a solution to the MacWilliams identities with all coefficients being nonnegative but *is not* the weight enumerator of any self-dual code of length $8$.

If self-dual codes are restricted to having weights that are multiples of $4$, then Gleason's results say that the weight enumerator can be expressed as a polynomial in
$x^8 + 14 x^4y^4 + y^8$ and
$x^4y^4(x^4-y^4)^4 = x^{20}y^4-4x^{16}y^8+6x^{12}y^{12}-4x^{8}y{16}+x^4y^{20}.$
The simplest example is the $[8,4]$ Hamming code whose weight enumerator is
$$x^8 + 14 x^4y^4 + y^8 = 1\cdot\big(x^8 + 14 x^4y^4 + y^8\big) + 0\cdot \big(x^{20}y^4-4x^{16}y^8+6x^{12}y^{12}-4x^{8}y{16}+x^4y^{20}\big).$$
The $[24,12]$ Golay code has weight enumerator
$$x^{24}+759x^{16}y^8 + 2576x^{12}y^{12}+759x^8y^{16}+y^{24}
= 1\cdot\big(x^8 + 14 x^4y^4 + y^8\big)^3-672\cdot\big(x^4y^4(x^4-y^4)^4\big)$$
but similar to the case of self-dual codes with even-weight codewords, one can find examples of solutions to the MacWilliams identities that have nonnegative  coefficients but are not the weight enumerators of any self-dual code.

All this just illustrates Jyrki Lahtonen's point that finding sufficient conditions on polynomials that will guarantee the existence of a code with the specified weight enumerator is a very difficult task.