# What kind of Symmetric Binary Linear Codes can satisfy my given specifications?

Tags: coding-theory

I am looking for a binary linear code $\mathcal{C}$ which is symmetric, meaning $\mathbf{1}\in\mathcal{C}$. Other than that, my other requirement for the code are: if $\mathcal{C}:=[n,k,d]_2$ is a symmetric code, where $n$ is the length of codewords, $k$ is the dimension of code, and $d$ is the minimum distance of codes, then I require the following:

(1). $n$ is large ( can be in the range of $500$ to $10,000$),

(2). $ \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-8 \leq d \leq  \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor -2$,

(3). $2^k\geq 4n$.

**I am imposing these restrictions on the code because this kind of code finds its application in compressed sensing.**

Here is what I have tried:

I constructed the symmetric BCH code with specifications $\mathcal{C}:=[8191, 14, 4095]_2$. As you can see here, $d=\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ and $2^k=2n+2$, but I need $2^k\geq 4n$. So, I thought that if I decrease the  value of $d$, then I might get $2^k \geq 4n$. But the catch here is, if I decrease the $d$ from $4095$, I get the new $d$ as $3968$, which means $d=\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor - 127$. I found that, in this case $d$ can not assume value in between $4095$ and $3968$. So, this kind of code is not useful for me because I also need to ensure that $ \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-8 \leq d \leq  \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor -2$.

So, here I am asking for your help. Can you tell me any if there exist any kind of code that fulfills my requirement? Any help or hint regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check the upper bound on $d$. $(n/2)-8$ is smaller than $(n/2)-2$, so $d$ cannot lie in between as you prescribed. The interval $(\lfloor n/2\rfloor-2,\lfloor n/2\rfloor-8)$ is empty!

Comment: With $d$ so close to $n/2$ there is not much elbow room. The constructions I can immediately reproduce do subtract something of the order $\sqrt n$ from $d$, if you increase the size of the code. But those also increase $k$ by about $\log_2n$ whereas you only want to increase it by one. I need to recall a few things. The (non-linear) Nordstrom-Robinson code would fit your requirements, but it has $n=16$ only, so way out of the  desired range.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}_4$-linear codes (so not quite but almost linear) sometimes add that one bit, but may also drop $d$ by a smaller multiple of $\sqrt n$. I need to check....

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ; I made a silly mistake in my question. I have edited it. I want my $d$ to lie in the interval $ \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-8 \leq d \leq  \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor -2$. Now, please answer my question.

Comment: If you want to see a small example of $\Bbb{Z}_4$-codes turned into binary, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118972/11619) I try  to explain how to get the Nordstrom-Robinson code ($n=16$, $d=6$, $M=2^8$ so in some sense $k=8$).

Comment: Anyway, you used (a punctured version of) the first order Reed-Muller $R(1,m)$ as your starting point. It has parameters $n=2^m$, $k=m+1$, $d=n/2$. If you want to extend that code to a linear code of dimension $k=m+2$, then it is easy to show that the minimum distance of the new code is at most $n/2-2^{m/2-1}$ (I can write a proof down, if you want to see it. The calculation is familiar to many from the theory of Bent functions). This doesn't prove anything, but it does accentuate the fact that a minimum distance a constant away from $n/2$ is a very tall order. May be impossible for high $n$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ; Ok, I got what you are saying. Basically, you are saying that the kind of code I am seeking is not possible to construct. My bad luck!

Comment: You wouldn't have prepared slides on the problem by any chance? May be something can be done anyway, just not as much as you initially hoped for? I'm not doubting your set up at all. I'm just a bit curious about how these code parameters/requirements emerged.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ; As I have already said, the kind of codeword I am seeking can be used in the construct compressed sensing matrices. I am a Ph.D. student, and I am in the final stage of my Ph.D. Before I get my degree I wanted to construct such kinds of compressed sensing matrices. If you want to discuss more about it, please share your email i.d.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I believe you can get a code of the type you want but won't quite get $d\geq n/2-8,$ as below from the Kerdock code via a construction due to Kiermaier and Zwanzger [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10623-012-9650-1). That's paywalled but the paper is available online elsewhere in paper-sharing sites.

[image]

You will not be able to get these parameters from a linear code. I don't know any other construction that would give what you want, since this construction builds on the original Kerdock via gray map construction, and is better than the best known way of getting more codewords via $\mathbb{Z}_4.$ See the end of this answer for more details and history.

This code has $n=1988$ and $M=2^12$ which is only $\geq 2n$ codewords. Its weight enumerator indicates codewords of weight $0,992,1024,1120.$

If you translate the code by the all 1's vector to double the number of codewords to $\geq 4n$ the weights will be $1988,1988-992,1988-1024,1988-1120$ which is $1988,996,964,868.$ The crucial question is the distances. I believe that the formal duality should establish the distance properties you need, but I am not so familiar with this construction. Perhaps @JyrkiLahtonen can comment. He may know a better construction.

*Background:* The Kerdock code's relationship to Z_4-linear codes was first discovered by Sole in 1991, and its full weight distribution, in the form of a quaternary sequence family (Family A) was given in Boztas' PhD thesis (1990) and later in Boztas, Hammons Kumar (1992), before the better known reference of the 5 authors paper which won the IT Transactions paper award in 1994. See the discussion in the Encyclopeadia of Mathematics online [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Kerdock_and_Preparata_codes) which has references to those papers.

Comment: Glad to see you discuss Kerdock codes! +1 I'm now in my office, and dug out my copy of the Hammons et al. paper. The weight distribution of the (symmetric) binary Kerdock code of length $2^{m+1}$ is concentrated on the weights $2^m$ and $2^m\pm2^{(m-1)/2}$, and we need $m$ to be odd. The OP wants $2^{(m-1)/2}=8$ implying that $m=7$. The code length thus maxes out at $n=256$. Schade.

Comment: FWIW I was somewhat heavily invested in the research on $\Bbb{Z}_4$-codes back in the day. My main contribution was to use the fact that the Galois rings can be constructed as rings of Witt vectors of length two over the fields $GF(2^m)$. That made learning the theory a lot simpler (my first born grad student used it). I was late to join in the party, so I only have a couple of papers to show for all that effort. C'est la vie :-)

Comment: I'm familiar with your work @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen ; You have said the weight distribution of the symmetric binary Kerdock code of length $2^{m+1}$ is concentrated on the weight on the weights $2^m$ and $2^m\pm 2^{(m-1)/2}$, and we need $m$ to be odd. But what can you say about the minimum and maximum distance of the code? Is the Kerdock code a linear code? The fact that $m$ needs to be odd is bad news for me.  Can you share anything using which I can construct these codes? I really need to construct these codes. Please help.